# How can I prevent MSVC++ from over-allocating stack space for a switch statement?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-optimization

As part of updating the toolchain for a legacy codebase, we would like to move from the Borland C++ 5.02 compiler to the Microsoft compiler (VS2008 or later). This is an embedded environment where the stack address space is predefined and fairly limited. It turns out that we have a function with a large switch statement which causes a much larger stack allocation under the MS compiler than with Borland's and, in fact, results in a stack overflow.

The form of the code is something like this:

```c++
#ifdef PKTS
#define RETURN_TYPE SPacket

typedef struct
{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
   int d;
   int e;
   int f;
} SPacket;

SPacket error = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
#else
#define RETURN_TYPE int

int error = 0;
#endif

extern RETURN_TYPE pickone(int key);

void findresult(int key, RETURN_TYPE* result)
{
   switch(key)
   {
      case 1   : *result = pickone(5 ); break;
      case 2   : *result = pickone(6 ); break;
      case 3   : *result = pickone(7 ); break;
      case 4   : *result = pickone(8 ); break;
      case 5   : *result = pickone(9 ); break;
      case 6   : *result = pickone(10); break;
      case 7   : *result = pickone(11); break;
      case 8   : *result = pickone(12); break;
      case 9   : *result = pickone(13); break;
      case 10  : *result = pickone(14); break;
      case 11  : *result = pickone(15); break;
      default  : *result = error;       break;
   }
}
```

When compiled with `cl /O2 /FAs /c /DPKTS stack_alloc.cpp`, a portion of the listing file looks like this:

```
_TEXT   SEGMENT
$T2592 = -264                       ; size = 24
$T2582 = -240                       ; size = 24
$T2594 = -216                       ; size = 24
$T2586 = -192                       ; size = 24
$T2596 = -168                       ; size = 24
$T2590 = -144                       ; size = 24
$T2598 = -120                       ; size = 24
$T2588 = -96                        ; size = 24
$T2600 = -72                        ; size = 24
$T2584 = -48                        ; size = 24
$T2602 = -24                        ; size = 24
_key$ = 8                       ; size = 4
_result$ = 12                       ; size = 4
?findresult@@YAXHPAUSPacket@@@Z PROC            ; findresult, COMDAT

; 27   :    switch(key)

    mov eax, DWORD PTR _key$[esp-4]
    dec eax
    sub esp, 264                ; 00000108H
...

$LN11@findresult:

; 30   :       case 2   : *result = pickone(6 ); break;

    push    6
    lea ecx, DWORD PTR $T2584[esp+268]
    push    ecx
    jmp SHORT $LN17@findresult
$LN10@findresult:

; 31   :       case 3   : *result = pickone(7 ); break;

    push    7
    lea ecx, DWORD PTR $T2586[esp+268]
    push    ecx
    jmp SHORT $LN17@findresult

$LN17@findresult:
    call    ?pickone@@YA?AUSPacket@@H@Z     ; pickone
    mov edx, DWORD PTR [eax]
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _result$[esp+268]
    mov DWORD PTR [ecx], edx
    mov edx, DWORD PTR [eax+4]
    mov DWORD PTR [ecx+4], edx
    mov edx, DWORD PTR [eax+8]
    mov DWORD PTR [ecx+8], edx
    mov edx, DWORD PTR [eax+12]
    mov DWORD PTR [ecx+12], edx
    mov edx, DWORD PTR [eax+16]
    mov DWORD PTR [ecx+16], edx
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [eax+20]
    add esp, 8
    mov DWORD PTR [ecx+20], eax

; 41   :    }
; 42   : }

    add esp, 264                ; 00000108H
    ret 0
```

The allocated stack space includes dedicated locations for *each case* to temporarily store  the structure returned from `pickone()`, though in the end, only one value will be copied to the `result` structure. As you can imagine, with larger structures, more cases, and recursive calls in this function, the available stack space is consumed rapidly.

If the return type is POD, as when the above is compiled without the `/DPKTS` directive, each case copies directly to `result`, and stack usage is more efficient:

```
$LN10@findresult:

; 31   :       case 3   : *result = pickone(7 ); break;

    push    7
    call    ?pickone@@YAHH@Z            ; pickone
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _result$[esp]
    add esp, 4
    mov DWORD PTR [ecx], eax

; 41   :    }
; 42   : }

    ret 0
```

Can anyone explain why the compiler takes this approach and whether there's a way to convince it to do otherwise? I have limited freedom to re-architect the code, so pragmas and the like are the more desirable solutions. So far, I have not found any combination of optimization, debug, etc. arguments that make a difference.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I understand that `findresult()` needs to allocate space for the return value of `pickone()`. What I don't understand is why the compiler allocates additional space for each possible case in the switch. It seems that space for one temporary would be sufficient. This is, in fact, how gcc handles the same code.  Borland, on the other hand, appears to use RVO, passing the pointer all the way down and avoiding use of a temporary. The MS C++ compiler is the only one of the three that reserves space for each case in the switch.

I know that it's difficult to suggest refactoring options when you don't know which portions of the test code can change -- that's why my first question is *why* does the compiler behave this way *in the test case*. I'm hoping that if I can understand that, I can choose the best refactoring/pragma/command-line option to fix it.

Comment: Rewrite the function to use a single call to `pickone`?

Comment: @K-ballo: He said he isn't allowed to rewrite it.

Comment: He said he isn't allowed to re-architect it: I didn't interpret that as barring a trivial rewrite of a single function body.

Comment: @Useless: It's trivial in a minimal example.  Probably not in the real codebase.  And you have to assume that any changes require new testing.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: He said he has limited freedom to rewrite it...

Comment: In the actual code, pickone() would be a different function for each case. So, the assembly does the function call within each case, but then jumps to a common block where the result is copied from the unique stack location to the `result` stack location.

Comment: @M.G. I'm sure that there's a combination of command line options or pragmas that could be used to achieve what you want, but figuring out what that combination might is, as you discovered, likely to be too involved. Can you, instead, refactor (or wrap around) the functions called in the `switch` so that they accept a pointer to `RETURN_TYPE` and use the pointer for storing their output?

Comment: That's certainly the most deterministic approach (in that it should always work, and doesn't depend on finding a suitable incantation for your optimizer)

Comment: This looks more like it shoudl have visual studio tag than C++.

Comment: Can you rewrite `findresult` to return the result? Then write a wrapper: `void findresult(int key, RETURN_TYPE* result) { *result = findresult(key);`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It didn't make a difference for me. Did it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just

```
void findresult(int key, RETURN_TYPE* result)
{
   if (key >= 1 && key <= 11)
     *result = pickone(4+key);
   else
     *result = error;
}
```

---

Assuming this counts as a smaller change, I just remembered an old question about scope, specifically related to embedded compilers. Does the optimizer do any better if you wrap each case in braces to explicitly limit the temporary scope?

```
switch(key)
{
   case 1   : { *result = pickone(5 ); break; }
```

---

Another scope-changing option:

```
void findresult(int key, RETURN_TYPE* result)
{
    RETURN_TYPE tmp;
    switch(key)
    {
      case 1   : tmp = pickone(5 ); break;
      ...
    }
    *result = tmp;
}
```

This is all a bit hand-wavy, because we're just trying to guess which input will coax a sensible response from this unfortunate optimizer.

Comment: First, I'm sure the `4+key` relationship doesn't exist in the real code.  But you could use the switch to get the arguments, and make a single call as K-ballo suggested.  However, OP said "I have limited freedom to re-architect the code".

Comment: Yeah, perhaps OP can clarify whether changing the function body counts as architecture in this context.

Comment: I had the same thought on scope changing. Unfortunately, neither change makes a difference.
Reduced examples are difficult to deal with, I know... In this case, assume the function can't be altered. There are multiple functions, and they don't all necessarily take arguments. The pickone() with arg was just a way to keep the example small while keeping the compiler from assuming it would always get the same return value from pickone().

Comment: I recalled this question when reading the gcc 4.7 [release notes](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html), since it _... now properly re-uses stack space allocated for temporary objects when their lifetime ends, which can significantly lower stack consumption for some C++ functions_. I don't suppose you're able to use gcc?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that rewriting that function is allowed, as long as the changes don't "leak" outside the function. I'm also assuming that (as mentioned in the comments) you actually have a number of separate functions to call (but that they all receive the same type of input and return the same result type).

For such a case, I'd probably change the function to something like:

```
RETURN_TYPE func1(int) { /* ... */ }
RETURN_TYPE func2(int) { /* ... */ }
// ...

void findresult(int key, RETURN_TYPE *result) { 
    typedef RETURN_TYPE (*f)(int);

    f funcs[] = (func1, func2, func3, func4, func5, /* ... */ };

    if (in_range(key))
        *result = funcs[key](key+4);
    else
        *result = error;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the idea. Essentially, it's a "build your own jump table" approach that mimics what the compiler ordinarily does with a switch statement, but forces efficient handling of the return value. Unfortunately, the real code won't neatly reduce to this format.

Comment: @M.G. You may need to show us the real code then so we can offer appropriate solutions.